# Splitting up file in Java Scanner using Regex

Tags: java, regex, split, java.util.scanner

I have the following data which I want to split :

1111|AAA|DDDD|CCC00021|RR13|600999922|101111287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000
2222|BBB|DDDD|CCC00031|RR15|600911122|101000287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000
3333|AAA|DDDD|CCC11021|RR01|600955522|101122287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000

Treating them like each line . I need to store each elements
to get an output of :

1111

AAA

DDDD

CCC00021

RR13

600999922

101111287

0

0

2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000

2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000

**Next line**

2222

BBB

DDDD

CCC00031

RR15

600911122

101000287

0

0

2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000

2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000

**Next Line**

3333

AAA

DDDD

CCC11021

RR01

600955522

101122287

0

0

2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000

2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000

I am using Scanner class.

Comment: So you want to replace "|" with " "? (Use String.replace(String,String)) or do you want to split the induvidual lines by "|". (Use String.split("\\|")).

Comment: Yes I want to Split them with " " . Than k_g  it worked .

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
String var = "1111|AAA|DDDD|CCC00021|RR13|600999922|101111287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000 2222|BBB|DDDD|CCC00031|RR15|600911122|101000287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000 3333|AAA|DDDD|CCC11021|RR01|600955522|101122287|0|0|2011-06-20 15:38:31.549000|2011-06-30 08:57:20.114000"

    for(String x : var.split("\\|")){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Comment: Yes sorry, it was for python :)